# UICollectionView images not showing

Tags: ios7, uicollectionview, popover

I have an issue with the images not showing, even though they are loading. I have tried this several different ways and the same result... no images. I do get white rectangles that are the size and color specified in the Storyboard. I get the correct number of rectangles in the popover. The log shows the names and ids correctly.

If I call the array directly, I get the same result... white rectangles.

My target is iOS7. Running Xcode 5.0.2. Images are coming from a SQL database. This is a live app, which I am updating to full iOS7 and where I am swapping out a custom grid layout for UICollectionView. Using a CollectionViewController, embedded into a NavigationController, which is accessed via a UIButton. As you can see, there is no custom cell. The images are to show in a popover and are then selectable by the user to change the background of the underlying view.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"BckgndCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDictionary * tempDict = [_arrayOfBckgnds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSNumber *buttonTagNumber = (NSNumber *)[tempDict objectForKey:@"id"];
    int buttonTag = [buttonTagNumber intValue];
    NSString *tempImage = [tempDict objectForKey:@"fileName"];

    NSLog(@"Filename: %@", tempImage);
    NSLog(@"ButtonTagNumber: %@", buttonTagNumber);
    UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
    image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:tempImage];
    NSLog(@"Image.image: %@", image.image);

    // needed for selecting the background in didSelectItemAtIndexPath
    _bgtag = buttonTag;

    return cell;
}
```

The fix which includes actually naming the BackgroundCell (duh) in the cellForItemAtIndexPath method and creating a small method in the BackgroundCell controller to set the image.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    BackgroundCell *cell = (BackgroundCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"BckgndCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDictionary * tempDict = [_arrayOfBckgnds objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSNumber *buttonTagNumber = (NSNumber *)[tempDict objectForKey:@"id"];
    int buttonTag = [buttonTagNumber intValue];
    NSString *tempImage = [tempDict objectForKey:@"fileName"];

    [cell setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:tempImage]];

    // needed for selecting the background in didSelectItemAtIndexPath
    _bgtag = buttonTag;

    return cell;
}
```

The main cell code;

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    _backgroundImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.contentView.bounds];

    [self.contentView addSubview:_backgroundImage];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)setImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    _backgroundImage.image = image;
}
```

Comment: I have the images showing now... took a long break for other work. Main thing, invoking the cell controller and a few other things. My fixes added above.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the image is not being set in the cell's view hierarchy. To do that, subclass UICollectionViewCell and create a `imageView` property in the subclass:

```
@interface CollectionViewCellSubclass : UICollectionViewCell
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *imageView;
@end
```

...and init the UIImageView in its `initWithFrame`:

```
_imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.contentView.bounds];
[self.contentView addSubview:_imageView];
```

Set this subclass as the Custom Class for the cell in storyboard and then load it in the `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath` method above setting the image to the cell's image subview:

```
CollectionViewCellSubclass *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"BckgndCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

//...

cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:tempImage];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This was close, but no cigar. See the fix in the main question area.

Comment: @MarcWatson the key point is that you've subclassed the `UICollectionViewCell` and added the `imageView` to its contentView. It should have been initialized in `initWithFrame` indeed so I made the edit above. The gist of the answer is accurate though and probably set you in the right path so perhaps it's worth being accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `cell.contentView.frame = [cell bounds]`  after the line `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier` worked for me.

Suppose you add a custom (200,200) `UICollectionViewCell` through xib and change its frame somewhere in the code to be e.g. (120,120). You have to set its content view’s frame accordingly, otherwise image on its `imageView` (which is on its content view) will not be shown properly.

Comment: You should have posted that info as an edit to your answer. I edited your comment in your answer for you.