# Custom UICollectionViewCell not showing UIImage and crashes

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm using a custom UICollectionViewCell which I call ExampleCell, within a UICollectionView, and the images I am trying to set for the cells are not showing up, and the app crashes. I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20566393/uicollectionview-images-not-showing), and I followed the comments to the best of my knowledge, but it didn't help.

When I comment out

```
self.collectionView!.registerClass(RedeemCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
```

inside ExampleCollectionViewController, the app doesn't crash but shows black boxes (since I set the cell background color to black) instead of the actual images. If I uncomment out that line, the app crashes with the error

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

**ExampleCollectionViewController.swift :**

```
import UIKit

private let reuseIdentifier = "ExampleCell"
private let sectionInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 50.0, left: 20.0, bottom: 50.0, right: 20.0)

class ExampleCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {
    let examples = Example.allExamples()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Register cell classes
        self.collectionView!.registerClass(ExampleCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

    override func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return examples.count
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> ExampleCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(reuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ExampleCell
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        cell.configureForExample(examples[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }
}
```

**ExampleCell.swift :**

```
import UIKit

class ExampleCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var exampleImageView: UIImageView!

    func configureForExample(example: Example) {
        exampleImageView.image = example.image
    }
}
```

**Example.swift**

```
import UIKit

@objc
class Example {
    let image: UIImage?

    init(image: UIImage?) {
        self.image = image
    }

    class func allExamples() -> Array<Example> {
        return [Example(image: UIImage(named: "Neutral")),
            Example(image: UIImage(named: "Sad")),
            Example(image: UIImage(named: "Happy")) ]
    }
}
```

In the Identity Inspector, I have custom classes set for ExampleCollectionViewController and ExampleCell. Also, in the Attributes Inspector, I have "ExampleCell" set as the Identifier under "Collection Reusable View" for ExampleCell.

Any ideas about what I may be doing incorrectly?

Comment: How do you create a cell ui? Is it in the storyboard as part of the collection view? Or is it a separate .xib file?

Comment: Either `exampleImageView` in your cell or `collectionView` in your view controller are `nil`? If you're getting the correct number of black boxes in your collection view then it's probably `exampleImageView` not bound in your xib/storyboard?

Comment: In the 'viewDidLoad' method you are registering 'ExampleCollectionViewCell' and in the 'cellForItemAtIndexPath ' method you are using 'ExampleCell'

Comment: @almas I used storyboard to create the cell UI

Comment: @Sebastian sorry that was a typo when I was editing. Will update my post.

Comment: @labanala you don't have to register anything with a collection view if you create your cell prototypes in the storyboard. That will fix your crash, as you already found out. As for the image not showing up - make sure that you connected your outlets correctly.

Comment: @almas When I go to storyboard, I see that under "Outlets" for ExampleCell has "exampleImageView -- Image View" and under "Referencing Outlets" for ImageView I have "exampleImageView -- ExampleCell". Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently if I set a background color and then try to set an image,

```
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        cell.configureForExample(examples[indexPath.row])
```

the black color shows up over the image. When I got rid of the line for the black background color, my images showed up. And to think I spent hours on this, lol.